# Get specific node from XML with XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, nodes

I have a XML-document like this:

```
<food>
<fruit>
    <apple>
        <product>
            <title>Apple 1</title>
            <price>7</price>
        </product>

        <product>
            <title>Apple 2</title>
            <price>4</price>
        </product>
    </apple>

    <grapes>
        <product>
            <title>Red grapes </title>
            <price>4</price>
        </product>
        <product>
            <title>Green grapes</title>
            <price>6</price>
        </product>
    </grapes>
</fruit>
<drink>
    <water>
        <product>
            <title>Water 1</title>
            <price>1</price>
        </product>
        <product>
            <title>Water 2</title>
            <price>6</price>
        </product>
    </water>
    <soda>
        <product>
            <title>Coca-Cola</title>
            <price>10</price>
        </product>
        <product>
            <title>Sprite</title>
            <price>4</price>
        </product>
    </soda>
</drink>
</food>
```

I have an XML structure like this.

I want to pick up the product name and price of all products that cost above 5. How do I write an XPath expression that does this?

Comment: Missed </ food>.

Of course, it be in the XML structure

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that your document ends with `</food>`. Is that what you want ?

```
//product[price > 5]
```

EDIT:

If you do not want the `<product>` tag, you can do that :

```
//product[price > 5]/*
```

However, I find this last solution less convenient, since we do not delimit the products any more.

Comment: Your example works, it gives me one result. But how do I do if I want to show everything? Do I need to loop with a for Each or can it be done without a loop?

Comment: Well, I am not friendly with XSLT (I use xquery). I suppose you will need to loop with a for-each (like here : http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/ ).

Comment: The XPath expressions in this answer give *all* results, not just one.  However the way you access the results outside of XPath will either extract a single string value, or a nodeset, or whatever. Your original question only asked about XPath, but now you need to tell us about the environment in which you're using XPath (is it in XSLT?)

Comment: @LarsH I supposed it was XSLT since the tags for this question mention it :)

Comment: @fflorent: a reasonable supposition. But sometimes people put tags on their questions without understanding or meaning much by them... So it's hard to know whether an xslt tag means "I'm using XSLT" or "I think XSLT may be part of the answer" or "I think XSLT has something to do with XPath".

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
  /*/*/*/product[price > 5]/title 
|
  /*/*/*/product/price[. > 5]
```

This selects the union of:

1. All `title` elements that have a `product` parent whose `price` child's string value when treated as a number is greater than 5  that is a great-grandson of the top element of the XML document.
2. All `price` elements whose string value when treated as a number is greater than 5, and  whose parent is a `product` that is a  great-grandson of the top element of the XML document.

The elements selected are provided in a node-set (typically) in document order, which means that a `title` and its corresponding `price` are next to each other in whatever collection of nodes is produced by the corresponding XPath API.

**In XSLT one would use a very simple transformation like this:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="product[price > 5]">
  Name: <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  <xsl:text>, price </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<food>
<fruit>
    <apple>
        <product>
            <title>Apple 1</title>
            <price>7</price>
        </product>

        <product>
            <title>Apple 2</title>
            <price>4</price>
        </product>
    </apple>

    <grapes>
        <product>
            <title>Red grapes </title>
            <price>4</price>
        </product>
        <product>
            <title>Green grapes</title>
            <price>6</price>
        </product>
    </grapes>
</fruit>
<drink>
    <water>
        <product>
            <title>Water 1</title>
            <price>1</price>
        </product>
        <product>
            <title>Water 2</title>
            <price>6</price>
        </product>
    </water>
    <soda>
        <product>
            <title>Coca-Cola</title>
            <price>10</price>
        </product>
        <product>
            <title>Sprite</title>
            <price>4</price>
        </product>
    </soda>
</drink>
</food>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  Name: Apple 1, price 7
  Name: Green grapes, price 6
  Name: Water 2, price 6
  Name: Coca-Cola, price 10
```

**It is even better to specify the price limit as a global parameter that is externally passed to the transformation.**

In this case an XSLT 2.0 transformation is a bit simpler:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pLimit" select="5"/>

 <xsl:template match="product[price > $pLimit]">
  Name: <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  <xsl:text>, price </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**A corresponding XSLT 1.0 transformation is**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pLimit" select="5"/>

 <xsl:template match="product">
  <xsl:if test="price > $pLimit">
      Name: <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      <xsl:text>, price </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```